# Importing Justgiving Data into civi

Tags: data-import

We have done a bit of searching and it looks like there is or was a just giving import by veda (https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.module.justgivingImports) that looks to be out of date.

I am wondering what people are using to import their justgiving report data into civi? Is it just the basic import process or are people using the JG API? Looking for this to be as easy as possible and suspect other UK charities will have faced this but I do not seem to see anything active on google searches.

Appreciate any help or pointers.